# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'instancemethod'

Tags: python, typeerror

this part is action transition probabilty

```
def _calculate_transition_prob(self, current, delta):
        new_position = np.array(current) + np.array(delta)
        new_position =self._limit_coordinates(new_position).astype(int)
        new_state = np.ravel_multi_index(tuple(new_position), self.shape)
        reward = self.reward
        is_done = self._cliff[tuple(new_position)] or (tuple(new_position) == (4,11))
        return [(1.0, new_state, reward, is_done)]
```

this part i want to use reward function as argument

```
def reward(reward, self):
    self.reward = -100.0 if self._cliff[tuple(new_position)] else -1.0
    return reward
```

this part is q learning (RL) algorithm

```
def q_learning(env, num_episodes, discount_factor=1.0, alpha=0.5, epsilon=0.1):

    Q = defaultdict(lambda: np.zeros(env.action_space.n))

    episode_lengths = np.zeros(num_episodes)
    episode_rewards = np.zeros(num_episodes)

    policy = epsilon_greedy_policy(Q, epsilon, env.action_space.n)

    for i_episode in range(num_episodes):
        state = env.reset()

        for t in itertools.count():
            action_probs = policy(state)
            action = np.random.choice(np.arange(len(action_probs)), p = action_probs)
            next_state, reward, done, _ = env.step(action)

            episode_rewards[i_episode] += reward
            episode_lengths[i_episode] = t
```

Comment: Where exactly is the error happening?

Answer (score 1):

Look at what you're doing with that statement: you try to add the *function object* `reward` to the left-hand side.  What does it mean to add a function object to something?  You need to write your code more clearly, so that you don't confuse the local `reward` variable with the visible `reward()` function.

I suspect that what you need is the return value from the function -- you would need to call it.  Again, I recommend that you give the variable and function separate names.